# foreign character è is not saving in mysql

Tags: mysql, character

the name "Eugène" became "EugÃ?ne". Please, give me a solution. I tried before by changing db character set but, still not working.

```
Connection id:          2939
Current database:       clcdb_final
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.5.32-log MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:            /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:                 45 min 59 sec
```

and table info: ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=57431 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: please provide more details. What is the collate and character set of the table, row and schema ?

Comment: Likely the problem is with how you connect to the database, not with the database itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check mySql connector jar version. if you using back dated jar then this can be happen.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have specified

> `"charset=utf8"`

in your connection string.

As noted in [Character Sets and Collations in General](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-general.html) 
MySQL can do:

- Store strings using a variety of character sets
- Compare strings using a variety of collations
- Mix strings with different character sets or collations in the same server, the same database, or even the same table
- Allow specification of character set and collation at any level

Comment: This has been resolved. I used old connector. Now i am using latest connector. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Verify that:

```
"charset=utf8"
```

And

```
Collation ==> utf8 - utf8_bin
```

Comment: This has been resolved. I used old connector. Now i am using latest connector. 

Thanks All